# Indenting with poemscol package

Tags: indentation, poetry

I'm trying to typeset a poem collection with [`poemscol`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/poemscol). The result looks like this:

[image: Screenshot showing how poemtitle and attribution are indented]

I'd like to control the distances marked in red (I don't want any moving to the right); but all attempts with `\setlength` of `\leftmargin`, `\titleindentamount` etc. don't work, and I've never ventured this far into page setup details. Can someone provide a hint how this usually works?

The current code:

```
\documentclass[9pt, a5paper]{scrbook}
\usepackage[a5paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{poemscol}
\begin{document}
\poemtitle{I dwell in Possibility}
\attribution{E. Dickinson (1830--1886)}
\begin{poem}
\begin{stanza}
\textsc{I dwell} in Possibility --\\
A fairer House than Prose --
\end{stanza}
\end{poem}
\end{document}
```

I tried to track the indentation in the `poemscol` package, but without success. I cannot find the commands in the package that control this behavior. What is their name and where are they?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You *can* insert pictures: use the normal way (clicking on the "screen" icon) and then remove the `!` before the reference to the picture. A user with enough reputation will reinstate the `!`.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It is considered a lot better to put in some code that will compile, as it makes it a lot easier for us to copy it into our text editor and work with it, and see exactly what it is you are trying to do.

Comment: I'm afraid that `poemscol` is rather rigid in its settings; the indentations are hard coded in the environments and not expressed by changeable parameters.

Answer (score 3):

In the most recent version of `poemscol`, you can adjust the left and right margins of epigraphs by changing the values of `\epigraphquoteleftmargin` or `\epigraphquoterightmargin`.

You can adjust the placement of the verse block by changing the value of
the length `\versemarginadjust`.

Comment: You will get more upvotes if you also provide a minimum working example that demonstrates the use of these parameters, for example, `\documentclass[9pt, a5paper]{scrbook}
\usepackage[a5paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{poemscol}
\epigraphquoteleftmargin=3em
\versemarginadjust = 4ex
\begin{document}
\poemtitle{I dwell in Possibility}
\attribution{E. Dickinson (1830--1886)}
\begin{poem}
\begin{stanza}
\textsc{I dwell} in Possibility --\\
A fairer House than Prose --
\end{stanza}
\end{poem}
\end{document}`

Answer (score 1):

The indentation of the poem author is indeed, as egreg has commented, hardcoded in the `epigraphquote` environment, so you have to change its definition. The environment used to typeset the poem proper is `pmclverse` (which inherits an optional argument from the `poem` environment). Its formula to determine margins only seems to allow to increase, but not to decrease the left margin, so I decided to change (simplify) its definition as well.

```
\documentclass[9pt, a5paper]{scrbook}
\usepackage[a5paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{poemscol}
\renewenvironment{epigraphquote}%
{\list{}{%
  \topsep 0pt%
  \partopsep 0pt%
  \listparindent 0pt%
  \leftmargin  1em% original value: 1.5em
  \rightmargin 1em% original value: 1.5em
}%
\item\relax}
{\endlist}
\makeatletter
\renewenvironment{pmclverse}[1][]{%
\let\\=\@centercr%
\list{}{%
  \itemsep\z@
  \itemindent -\runoverindentvalue
  \listparindent \itemindent
  \leftmargin 2em% change as desired
  \rightmargin 2em% change as desired
  \advance\leftmargin\runoverindentvalue
}%
\item[]}
{\endlist}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\poemtitle{I dwell in Possibility}
\attribution{E. Dickinson (1830--1886)}
\begin{poem}
\begin{stanza}
\textsc{I dwell} in Possibility --\\
A fairer House than Prose --
\end{stanza}
\end{poem}
\end{document}
```